# NullPointerException while accessing HSQLDB database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

I am accessing HSQLDB through A jdbc drive in my java program. The script file of the database is as follows.

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA

CREATE CACHED TABLE TBL1(ID CHAR(5),NAME VARCHAR(11),ZIP VARCHAR(11))

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_ID ON TBL1(ID)

CREATE CACHED TABLE TBL2(ID CHAR(5),STREET CHAR(5))

CREATE INDEX IDX_RS_ID ON TBL2(ID)

CREATE CACHED TABLE TBL3(ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,LON FLOAT,LAT FLOAT)

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY MEMORY TABLE OVERLAY(ID CHAR(8),AROUTE CHAR(10),ZROUTE 

CHAR(10),TYPE CHAR(8)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

SET TABLE TBL1 INDEX'4490648 5643624 0'

SET TABLE TBL2 INDEX'529105280 529105280 0'

SET TABLE TBL3 INDEX'775814624 0'

CREATE VIEW OVERLAYSPAN (ID,STREET) AS SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME FROM OVERLAY AS O, TBL2 as 
R WHERE O.ID = R.ID

CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""

GRANT DBA TO SA

SET WRITE_DELAY 10
```

In the java program, I am first removing all entries (1000 entries) from TBL1 and reinserting new entries (1500) in the same table. The program executes normally, but, when I am attempting to re-execute the same program, I am getting the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 9 S1000 General error 

java.lang.NullPointerException in statement [SET TABLE TBL2 INDEX'529105280 529105280 0']
```

Here is the fill stack trace from the program.

```
java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 9 S1000 General error java.lang.NullPointerException in statement [SET TABLE TBL2 INDEX'529105280 529105280 0']
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at HSQLTesting.main(HSQLTesting.java:98)
```

Where at line 98, the program is attempting to make a connection with the database.

```
Connection sqlconnect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/birdseyedb/birdseye", "SA", "");
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? I have a feeling the NPE is caused by another exception.

Comment: You can edit your existing question with the stack trace. The one you just posted doesn't tell the full story. Do you, by any chance, see a java out-of-memory error in the **full** stack trace?

Comment: No, I didn't see java out of memory error in my stack trace.